# JavaScript: X.prototype.x adds x to base class, too

Tags: javascript, polymorphism

I'm fluent in C++ so I have a good background in OOP, but I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to understand how to properly implement polymorphism in JavaScript.  I have read a number of tutorials and StackOverflow questions related to this topic, but none has explained in detail how to correctly *inherit* from a base class and also *add new members* to the child class.

```
function Obj1() {}
function Obj2() {}
function Obj3() {}

Obj2.prototype === Obj3.prototype;  // false
```

**Curiosity #1:**  If both `Obj2` and `Obj3` (and, for that matter, `Obj1`) inherit from `Object`, why are their prototypes not identical?  Did `Obj2` and `Obj3` each receive its own *copy* of `Object`?

```
Obj2.prototype = Object;
Obj2.prototype = Object;
Obj2.prototype === Obj3.prototype;  // true
Obj2.prototype = Obj1;
Obj3.prototype = Obj1;
Obj2.prototype === Obj3.prototype;  // true
```

**Curiosity #2:**  In both cases, `Obj2` and `Obj3` now share the same prototype.  What has changed?

```
Obj2.prototype.pi = function() {  return 3.14159;  }
Obj2.prototype.pi();  // 3.14159
Obj3.prototype.pi();  // 3.14159
Obj1.pi();  // 3.14159
```

**The Real Question:**  Changing the prototype of `Obj2` also changes the prototype of `Obj3` and the function `Obj1` itself.  This is all quite shocking to this C++ programmer, even though it's exactly what I expected from the above syntax: after all, since the prototypes of `Obj2` and `Obj3` have both been equated with `Obj1`, a change to one will produce an identical change to the other two.  Nevertheless, I want to use `Obj1` as a base class for both `Obj2` and `Obj3` *and* insert a new function on `Obj2` that is *not* shared in any way by `Obj1` or `Obj3`.  How do I do that?

**Further curiosities** arise when these objects are instantiated:

```
var x = new Obj2();
x.pi();  // 3.14159
var y = new Obj3();
y.pi();  // 3.14159
var z = new Obj1();
z.pi();  // Error: pi() not defined on z.
```

`Obj2` and `Obj3` both have a function `pi()`, which implies that they still share a *base class* that contains a function `pi()`.  This base class is none other than `Obj1`—but an instance of `Obj1` does *not* contain `pi()`, despite the evidence to the contrary!

Comment: The first thing to do is to fully accept the fact that inheritance in JavaScript is a completely different affair than inheritance in C++.  It's really only superficially related; it's based on a completely different conceptual model.

Comment: Oh and in particular, there's really no such concept as "class" in JavaScript.  There are effects you can get that allow you to *pretend* that there are classes, but it's just a convention.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)

Comment: You may also be interested in reading [javaScript class functions](http://metadea.de/V/).

Answer (score 2):

In your first proof:

```
function a () {};
function b () {};

a.prototype === b.prototype; // false
```

You're hitting on the fact that the `prototype` isn't `Object` -- it's not the base class.
It's an object, which is in turn extended, prototypically, with the methods and properties of `Object`.
And any test of `{} === {};` is going to return false, ***always***, unless you're testing two pointers to the same object:

```
var a = {},
    b = a;

a === b; // true
```

Your inheritance trainwreck afterwards points directly to missing this concept, as you've set all three functions to point to the same object (originally to `Object` itself, and then to `Obj1`'s prototype object).
A `prototype` is ***live***, any change to the prototype, after object construction, will reflect in the objects containing a pointer to that object.

You've given `Obj1`, `Obj2` and `Obj3` a pointer to the exact same object.
Ergo, any modifications to that prototype object they all share will reflect in all of their constructed objects, as inheritance-resolution happens in real-time, when you attempt to access a property (rather than living in some static, pre-compiled, GOTO state).

If you wanted the ability to subclass, you could do something like this:

```
var A = function () {};
A.prototype.foo = function () {};
var a = new A();

var B = function () {};
B.prototype = a; // or new A(); -- an object which can live-lookup the prototype of A
// problem is, `constructor` on the prototype will now point to `A`, so...
B.prototype.constructor = B; // now b instanceof B should work in tests
B.bar = function () {};


var b = new B();
b.foo(); // A.prototype.foo
b.bar(); // B.prototype.bar
```

But really, you're going to drive yourself crazy if you try to extend this too far.
A saner path to follow in JS is component-based object construction, and dependency-injection.

Answer (score 1):

The `prototype` property returns an object as well, which is an instance of object but not the same instance, so they are not the same object and a comparison for equality naturally returns false.

In more detail, Obj1, Obj2 and Obj3 are all functions and objects, and their prototypes are also objects. In C++ terms, think of the `prototype` property as a pointer to another object, not the class definition or the base class.

In the case of Obj2, you'd declare a separate method like this:

```
function Obj2() {
    this.prototype = new Obj1();
    this.myOwnMethod = function (x) { ... }
}
```

I was trying to put to writing in my own words a good explanation of object orientation in Javascript, but I think that would take too long :) instead I decided to delete what half-coherent text I wrote and give two pointers that helped me understand it in more depth, hopefully they will help you, too:

- [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
- [Crockford on Javascript presentation series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM&feature=BFa&list=PL62E185BB8577B63D)

Answer (score -3):

Use [ember](http://emberjs.com/) or [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) or some other framework to extract this for you. There's a lot of monkeying required to get inheritance to work like you expect.

Comment: Please try to answer the question, not provide tangents

Comment: It's not a tangent. If you're doing JS development and trying to use raw prototypes, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: :) Ok, now this discussion is another useless tangent. There's no harm in knowing more about what you work with and how it works. The backbone people sure did do their reading, so they were wrong?

Comment: It's a waste of time, and time is money. And if I was a developer on the OP's team, I'd tell him to stop dicking around and use a framework. That's the state of javascript development right now. You use a framework.

Someone migrating from C++ might not know this offhand.

Comment: :) Ok, if you believe so, good for you. I believe knowing is better than believing blindly, or worse not knowing, not caring and skimming over. Part of being a better programmier imo. Time is money, and in the long run, this saves more money and time.

Comment: Downvoting not for suggesting a framework, but for suggesting two MVC/MVP style frameworks without bothering to ask what problem OP was trying to solve.